# How to parse a really long text string into multiple row values in SSIS?

Tags: ssis, text-files

I have a single flat file with just 1 row of data that is about 1896 columns wide. Technically speaking, its the same type of data that is all made up onto a single row rather then having them on multiple rows with CR/LF.

My question is how do I make this 1 row split into multiple rows? Sample of the data is as follows:

```
96859471/971 AAAA HAWAII               96860471/971 BBBB HAWAII               96861471/971 CCCC HAWAII               96863471/971 DDDD HAWAII
```

Comment: What version of SQL Server are you working with?

Comment: SQL Server 2016

Answer (score 2, accepted):

With SQL Server 2016 and up (in at least compatibility level 130) you can leverage the [`STRING_SPLIT`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/string-split-transact-sql?view=sql-server-2017) function.

The function will break up a row into a table based on a single character delimiter between entries. Since you have multiple spaces between values, you'll want to `REPLACE` those with a single character. I used a vertical pipe, `|`, but you may choose something even more obscure.

Also, I used `TRIM` to ditch the trailing spaces.

```
DECLARE @s NVARCHAR(MAX) = '96859471/971 AAAA HAWAII               96860471/971 BBBB HAWAII               96861471/971 CCCC HAWAII               96863471/971 DDDD HAWAII               '

SELECT @s = REPLACE(TRIM(@s),'               ','|')

SELECT value FROM STRING_SPLIT(@s,'|');
```

Results:

```
+--------------------------+
|          value           |
+--------------------------+
| 96859471/971 AAAA HAWAII |
| 96860471/971 BBBB HAWAII |
| 96861471/971 CCCC HAWAII |
| 96863471/971 DDDD HAWAII |
+--------------------------+
```

You should be able to encapsulate this in an Execute SQL Task, then return it to an object variable, or drop it into a table directly. Whatever your specifications require.